# Does calling USCIS on an OPT application before 75 days slow down processing time?

Tags: usa, student-visa

On [this site](https://oissmsu.wordpress.com/2016/03/28/all-you-need-to-know-about-opt-processing-delays/) from 2016, it reports,

> After applying for OPT, how long should I wait before trying to contact USCIS.
>
> Please note that excessive contact with USCIS can actually slow down your OPT application, so it’s best to keep you contact minimal!
>
> **OPT APPLICATION (I-765) PENDING LESS THAN 75 DAYS**
>
> It is within the normal processing period. No need to do anything.

Is this still valid advice? If you know other people that applied after you and received first and the web site isn't updating, is it a good idea to call before 75 days, or after?